# Downloading Sentinel 2 imagery using Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, remote-sensing, sentinel-2

I have been following this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcETq8OWM0k) to download Sentinel 2 imagery using the [Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/) in QGIS 3. However, when I click run and select the folder to download the files into, there is just a beeping sound and the files do not download. These are the settings I have been using:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the last image you have the tick box enabled for "Only if preview in Layers". This means that only bands you have selected to preview in the layers panel will be downloaded. Try de-selecting it.

Answer (score 5):

In the last image you have the tick box enabled for "Only if preview in Layers". This means that only bands you have selected to preview in the layers panel will be downloaded. Try de-selecting it.